# How to cast to generic array?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write generic functionality to load a list of objects using core data, I pass the entity name and the array type. The app crashes when casting to the generic array...

```
func load<T>(#entityName:String, type:T.Type) -> T {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    var error:NSError?
    let obj = appDelegate.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as T

    return obj
}
```

I call it like this:

```
self.load(entityName: "CDSection", type: [CDSection].self)
```

Note that without the generic functionality, it works:

```
let obj = appDelegate.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [CDSection]
```

As a test,  I tried passing only the type of the element, not the array, and returning an array with elements of this type... this **works**, but I would like to just pass the array type, in the case I also can load things that are not arrays.

```
func load<T:AnyObject>(#entityName:String, type:T.Type) -> [T] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    var error:NSError?
    let obj = appDelegate.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [T]

    return obj
}
```

And call it like this:

```
self.load(entityName: "CDSection", type: CDSection.self)
```

Then I experimented a bit but without success, for example...

```
func load<T:[AnyObject]>(#entityName:String, type:T.Type) -> T {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    var error:NSError?
    let obj = appDelegate.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as T

    return obj
}
```

There I get "Expected a type name or protocol composition restricting 'T'" in the first line, because, apparently [AnyObject] isn't a valid restriction for T...?

How can I implement what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find your other approach (returning `[T]`) more natural, as a fetch request will always return an array of managed objects.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I wasn't sure about that. Anyways I'm interested in knowing why I can't pass [T].